# location code example doesn't work

Tags: android, android-location

I am trying to run the code below to get the user location (altitude/latitude/longitude) but it's not working. On logCat I am getting the following error messages:

**07-15 02:59:47.575: ERROR/vold(26): Error opening switch name path '/sys/class/switch/test' (No such file or directory)**

**07-15 02:59:47.575: ERROR/vold(26): Error bootstrapping switch '/sys/class/switch/test' (No such file or directory)**

**07-15 02:59:47.575: ERROR/vold(26): Error opening switch name path '/sys/class/switch/test2' (No such file or directory)**

**07-15 02:59:47.575: ERROR/vold(26): Error bootstrapping switch '/sys/class/switch/test2' (No such file or directory)**

**07-15 03:00:15.075: ERROR/BatteryService(60): usbOnlinePath not found**

**07-15 03:00:15.075: ERROR/BatteryService(60): batteryVoltagePath not found**

**07-15 03:00:15.075: ERROR/BatteryService(60): batteryTemperaturePath not found**

**07-15 03:00:15.134: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(60): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake**

**07-15 03:00:25.965: ERROR/EventHub(60): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter**

**07-15 03:00:25.975: ERROR/EventHub(60): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter**

**07-15 03:00:26.404: ERROR/System(60): Failure starting core service**

**07-15 03:00:26.404: ERROR/System(60): java.lang.SecurityException**

**07-15 03:00:26.404: ERROR/System(60):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)**
**07-15 03:00:26.404: ERROR/System(60):     at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)**

**07-15 03:00:26.404: ERROR/System(60):     at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)**

**07-15 03:00:26.404: ERROR/System(60):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:176)**

**07-15 03:00:26.414: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(60): Crash logging skipped, no checkin service**

**07-15 03:00:49.123: ERROR/vold(26): Cannot start volume '/sdcard' (volume is not bound)**

**07-15 03:00:51.363: ERROR/MediaPlayerService(30): Couldn't open fd for content://settings/system/notification_sound**

**07-15 03:00:51.443: ERROR/MediaPlayer(60): Unable to to create media player**

**07-15 03:00:54.393: ERROR/ActivityThread(106): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin**

**07-15 03:00:58.313: ERROR/ActivityThread(106): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin**

**07-15 03:00:58.533: ERROR/ActivityThread(106): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin**

**07-15 03:01:04.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(131): ERROR: thread attach failed**

**07-15 03:01:19.295: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(174): ERROR: thread attach failed**

**07-15 03:01:26.345: ERROR/ActivityThread(60): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings**

**07-15 03:01:26.355: ERROR/ActivityThread(60): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings**

**07-15 03:01:27.236: ERROR/ActivityThread(214): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings**

**07-15 03:01:27.256: ERROR/ActivityThread(214): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings**

**07-15 03:01:27.375: ERROR/ActivityThread(214): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings**

**07-15 03:01:48.195: ERROR/gralloc(60): [unregister] handle 0x384650 still locked (state=40000001)**

**07-15 03:01:57.138: ERROR/ActivityThread(60): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin**

**07-15 03:01:57.346: ERROR/gralloc(60): [unregister] handle 0x11ee50 still locked (state=40000001)**

What could be wrong/missing?

**Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="net.learn2develop.Location"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">


        <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <!-- uses-library android:name="android.location" /-->        
        <!--fim insercao -->    
        <activity android:name=".AppStart"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES" />    

</manifest>
```

**Java Code:**

```
package net.learn2develop.Location;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;


import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class AppStart extends MapActivity { 
    private LocationManager myLocationManager; 
    private LocationListener myLocationListener; 
    private MapView myMapView; 
    private MapController myMapController; 
    private List<Overlay> mapOverlays;
//Button gpsON;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private void CenterLocation(GeoPoint centerGeoPoint) {

    mapOverlays = myMapView.getOverlays();
    myMapController.animateTo(centerGeoPoint);
    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.icon);
    HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(
            drawable, this);

    //OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(centerGeoPoint);    
    //itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

};
@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //gpsON = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mapView);    

    myMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    myMapView.setSatellite(true);
    myMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    // Set satellite view
    myMapController = myMapView.getController();
    myMapController.setZoom(15);

    // Fixed Zoom Level




    mapOverlays = myMapView.getOverlays();

    myLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    myLocationListener = new MyLocationListener();
    myLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,          
        0, 0, myLocationListener); 
    //myLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,            
    //        0, 0, myLocationListener); 


    // Get the current location in start-up

    GeoPoint initGeoPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (myLocationManager
            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)            
            .getLatitude() * 1E6), (int) (myLocationManager     
            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
            .getLongitude() * 1E6));  
    CenterLocation(initGeoPoint);

}



private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location argLocation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        GeoPoint myGeoPoint = new GeoPoint(
                (int) (argLocation.getLatitude() * 1E6),
                (int) (argLocation.getLongitude() * 1E6));
        CenterLocation(myGeoPoint);
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}

public class HelloItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {
    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    private Context mContext;

    public HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    mContext = context;
    }

    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
        mOverlays.add(overlay);
        populate();
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        return mOverlays.get(i);
    }

@Override
    public int size() {
        return mOverlays.size();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onTap(int index) {
    OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
        dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
        dialog.show();
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
};
}
```

tnx in advance